# How to denormalize YAML for Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yaml, denormalization

I am trying to get data from a YAML file into a Pandas DataFrame.  Take the following example `data.yml`:

```
---
 - doc: "Book1"
   reviews:
     - reviewer: "Paul"
       stars: "5"
     - reviewer: "Sam"
       stars: "2"
 - doc: "Book2"
   reviews:
     - reviewer: "John"
       stars: "4"
     - reviewer: "Sam"
       stars: "3"
     - reviewer: "Pete"
       stars: "2"
...
```

The desired DataFrame would look like this:

```
     doc reviews.reviewer reviews.stars
0  Book1             Paul             5
1  Book1              Sam             2
2  Book2             John             4
3  Book2              Sam             3
4  Book2             Pete             2
```

I've tried feeding the YAML data to Pandas different ways (like `with open('data.yml') as f: data = pd.DataFrame(yaml.load(f))`), but the cells always contain the nested dicts.  This [solution works for general JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46351407/1717828), but it's quite a bit of code and it seems like a simpler solution for YAML might exist.

Is there a built-in or Pythonic way to denormalize YAML for conversion to a Pandas Dataframe in this way?

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Comment: Couldn't you use something like pyyaml to just read in the yaml as an object and then load it to df?

Comment: "It seems like a simpler solution for YAML might exist" Why do you think so, because YAML is a superset of JSON and the parser for YAML at least a magnitude more complex? You don't indicate how you get to `yaml`, but if that is the PyYAML module it is both unnecessary and potentially dangerous to use `yaml.load()`.

Comment: Can you please let me know if `json_normalize` solved your problem?

Comment: @coldspeed Aye, it did, hence the upvote (I guess the question phrased well enough for an upvote?).  Saved me a lot of time.  I like to give questions a few days before marking as answered in case someone else has a different way, but I'll likely be marking yours as accepted by the end of the weekend.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The downvote was not from me, but yeah I think the question was well enough asked. Better than a lot I've seen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion of YAML Data to Data Frame using yamltodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892662/conversion-of-yaml-data-to-data-frame-using-yamltodb)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) to flatten the dictionary after YAML loads:

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(yaml.load(f), 'reviews', 'doc')

  reviewer stars    doc
0     Paul     5  Book1
1      Sam     2  Book1
2     John     4  Book2
3      Sam     3  Book2
4     Pete     2  Book2
```

Answer (score 7):

Using above now leads to
FutureWarning: pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated, use pandas.json_normalize instead

```
# lets say the yaml file is test_sample.yml
from pandas import json_normalize
from os import getcwd, path
from yaml import SafeLoader, load

path_to_yaml = path.join(getcwd(), ..., "test_sample.yaml")
with open(path_to_yaml) as yaml_file:
    yaml_contents = load(path_to_file, Loader=SafeLoader)
yaml_df = json_normalize(yaml_contents)
```